# immutable js update a key in Record

Tags: immutable.js

So I have an Immutable js Record:

```
{
 title: "item 1",
 title2: "item 2",
 title3: "item 3"
}
```

I want to update the keys, so it will become:

```
{
  new title: "item 1",
  title2: "item 2",
  title3: "item 3"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use delete keyword, to delete a particular key and then use Object.assign to append it as below:

```js
let hello1={ title: "item 1", title2: "item 2", title3: "item 3"}; 

delete hello1['title'];

console.log(Object.assign({'new title': "item 1"}, hello1));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
let obj = Immutable.fromJS({
    title: "item 1",
    title2: "item 2",
    title3: "item 3"
});
```

// One liner

```
obj = obj.set('new_title', obj.get('title')
         .delete('title');
```